# How to check multiple cells one at a time VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the code below for a graph. I want to check each cell in the Range("C9:AG9") separately then depending on if that cell IsEmpty = True then it ClearContents of the corresponding Column (Rows 5:8). What is the best way to write this code to have it check each cell independently instead of writing this 31 times for each column?

```
If IsEmpty(Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C9").Value) = True Then
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C5:C8").ClearContents
End If
```

Comment: You might want to research `For Each` loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fast solution without for loop

```
Sub ClearAtEmpty()
    Dim empty_cells As Range
    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        On Error Resume Next    'switch off error trapping (if no empty cells in the range, the next line will raise the error)
        Set empty_cells = .Range("C9:AG9").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)   'get all the empty cells in the range
        On Error GoTo 0         ' switch on error trapping
        If Not empty_cells Is Nothing Then  ' if there are empty cells
            Intersect(empty_cells.EntireColumn, .Rows("5:8")).ClearContents
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Short option (...but not so clear and masking errors)

```
Sub ClearAtEmptyShort()
    On Error Resume Next    'switch off error trapping (if no empty cells in the range, the next line will raise the error)
    Intersect(Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C9:AG9").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireColumn, Worksheets("sheet1").Rows("5:8")).ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: That is actually very nice solution :)

Comment: The `Error` object is global, so there is no exception for not turning off error trapping with e.g. `On Error Goto 0` when using `On Error Resume Next` (at least it's not correct). Try this little example: 1.) `Sub Test1(): On Error Resume Next: Err.Raise 9: End Sub`
2.) `Sub Test2(): Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description: End Sub`
3.) `Sub Test3(): Test1: Test2: End Sub`. Run the `Test3` procedure and see the result. Now add `On Error Goto 0` appropriately to the first procedure to see the difference after running the `Test3` procedure. Can you ensure that a procedure will not be called?

Comment: A side note: `xlCellTypeBlanks` will 'correctly' return, as OP requested, only **empty** cells although it implies differently: **blanks** i.e. cells containing `=""` or `'` will not be included.

Comment: If you in the `With` statement do `Dim rg As Range: Set rg = .Range("C9:AG9")` then you can test with e.g. `If Application.CountA(rg) < rg.Columns.Count Then` or alternatively even `If WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(3, rg) < rg.Columns.Count Then`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim i as Integer

for i = 0 to 30 'loop certain number of times
    'check if nullstring / also can do isempty function
    if Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C9").Offset(0,i) = vbnullstring then 
         'delete on offset
         Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C5:C8").Offset(0,i).ClearContents
    end if
next i
```

you could also use foreach but i think limited for is better solution in this case.

Comment: Empty means only `Empty`, while blank means `Empty`, `=""`, `'`. If the cell contains one of the latter two, `IsEmpty` will return `False`: the cells just look like they are empty, but they are blank. So to include the two cases not covered by `IsEmpty`, you can do `cCell.Value = vbNullString` or `cCell = ""` or `Len(cCell.Value) = 0`, all three yielding the same result. But I think OP wants just `IsEmpty`. If you don't use the `With` statement, use a variable, and qualifying objects is also a good idea: `Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` ... `If ws.Range(...`.

Comment: For me would actually name the sheet and set the range & then go with `with`, but I didn't want to confuse the OP, so i tried to write on approx. same level so it would be clear what is going on :) As for `IsEmpty`, you are right, that's why i had added comment.